# PHP echo from MySQL variable split price with commas?

Tags: php

I have a column in the database called price that stores values like 200000 and I've been able to successfully use MySQL to split this up by comma like 200,000 but my understanding is that this is not a very good use of MySQL syntax and could be a disaster on larger queries.

How do I take this as a PHP variable and perform the same thing?

Example:  `echo '<title>$' . $price . '.00- ' .`

Comment: number_format() or money_format()

Comment: use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) php function

Comment: note: `money_format()` doesn't always work on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/number_format)

```
echo '<title>$' . number_format($price) . '.00';
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo '<title>$' . number_format($price) . '';`

Answer (score 1):

[number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Added number after decimal

```
echo '<title>$' . number_format($price,2) . '.00';
```

Comment: You might want to drop the concatenation of '.00' if you're using number_format()